# What do you call the voice-acting and motion-capture combined?

Tags: word-request

So Ryan Reynold is Detective Pikachu in the upcoming Pokemon film, but he's not only voice-acting for Pikachu, but doing the motion capture. So what do you call the act of doing both? Is there a word for it?

Comment: `but he's not only voice-acting for Pikachu, but doing the motion capture.`  I think you've already got the most clear and concise phrasing right here.  Anything more obscure will lose some of your readers.

Answer (score 2):

The person who does the voice and facial capture (and occasional full motion capture) for a completely CGI-rendered character is still call the *actor* for the role.  There is, as of yet, no special term for this combined, as it's generally going to be the same person.

At least for the scenes that show detailed characterization, such as dialogue and facial expressions.  For the more physical action scenes, stuntmen (and women, of course) are used.  These are collectively referred to as *mocap actors*.

Comment: I believe we'll be ahead of the curve if we coin the phrase *vomocap actors*!